# Any native solution against windows that are always-on-top?

Tags: windows-7, always-on-top

In Windows 7, several Steam games place themselves on top of all windows. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works. It brings up the list of windows and if I hover the mouse on top of an icon, the window eventually shows on top of the game. But if I click it, the game places itself on top again.

(This is actually inconsistent. Because sometimes, with no pattern that I can notice, I manage to switch applications.)

With one specific game, resorting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to minimize the window from there is not helping. The game screen in simply replaced by a plain white frame that remains on top.

I'm aware of at least one [third-party application](https://superuser.com/a/1036652/680604) that could possibly solve that. But I would appreciate if someone could help me find a solution that didn't involve installing third-party software -- especially one that doesn't seem to have been maintained in 13 years.

Comment: Complain to the game's developer (or uninstall the thing?)

Comment: That's one way, sure. But not really the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: there's no built-in solution in Windows regarding changing a window's on top status. It's just about setting a flag so an old software work just as well, unless MS decided to completely change how the program windows are handled, which can't happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable window always-on-top](https://superuser.com/questions/176394/disable-window-always-on-top)