# How to prevent a window from being always on top?

Tags: windows-10, window, gui

I am using Windows 10 Professional, Version 1703, build 15063.

A program (its window) which I am using has (I believe) a hard-coded "always on top" behavior. There is no option within this program to disable this behavior.

I know there are ways to force a window to be always on top. However I am looking for the exact opposite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable window always-on-top](https://superuser.com/questions/176394/disable-window-always-on-top)

Answer (score 1):

The way "Always on top" works is simple. You basically set a flag on the program. In more programmatical sense, you set the z-order to a high number, but that doesn't really matter for this answer.

The thing is, when a program allows you to set any window on top, it will almost always also have a feature to undo this. Because it is just altering the property of a window, and not somehow "keep" it in front, any program that can set any window as "always on top" should therefor also be able to undo this.

There are even programs that can do this on a rule base. If program x is detected, automatically set its always on top state to x. I don't know a free program that can do this, and software recommendations are off-topic too, but given your question, I'm pretty sure you already saw them.

Comment: You are a legend LPChip .. I type stupid crap.. re-read your post and realize I jumped the gun and as you specified there is no HWND_NOTTOPMOST flag.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thank you. :)